# Show that a ring with only trivial right ideals is either a division ring or $|R|=p$ and $R^2=\{0\}$. Why would $R$ be finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let  $R$  be  a  ring  such  that  the  only  right  ideals  of  $R$  are  $(0)$  and  $R$.  Prove  that  either  $R$  is  a  division  ring  or  that  $R$  is  a  ring  with  a  prime  number  of  elements  in  which  $ab=  0$  for  all  $a,b\in R$.

I  don't  want  the  proof.  I  am  stuck  at  one  point.  Why  does $R$  have  to  be  finite  here?

Comment: @rschwieb, I think that the answer in the original question is a bit lacking though. However the OP's doubt is indeed settled there.

Comment: @Hmm. I believe there are already at least two copies of this question (if not more) out there, and this was the first match I found. Maybe one of the others is even better...

Comment: @rio In the future, please use the search feature and pay attention to related question titles that pop up as you title your question. The thing I linekd as a duplicate was detected by the Related column.

Comment: I couldn't find those related questions. But still I am only demanding for a little help, not the entire proof.

Comment: @rschwieb you have marked my question as duplicate, but the question you mentioned above as the original one has silly and incomplete answer. So can you please refer me with a question with correct answer or answer it yourself?

Comment: Dear @RioDutta : The solution you accepted here is far more incomplete than the one I referred to, so I'm not very impressed by your comment. At any rate, I pointed out the missing step in a comment.

Comment: @RioDutta : you may take a look at the further comments and the other answer in the question linked ....

Comment: @rschwieb I asked the question asking only about the finiteness of the ring, which  Hmm. answered, so I accepted his answer.

Comment: @RioDutta Sorry, when one person posts a question and it gets answered, and another person posts a subquestion of the same question that is already answered by the older post, I believe it should be flagged as duplicate. Sorry I misjudged the quality of the already existing answer, but I have done my best to make sure that the duplicate does now indeed is sufficient. I see your point and I'll be careful as I read your posts, I promise :)

Comment: @rschwieb please look at my question again. My ring isn't commutative, so how can I prove it a division ring? I thought I had done the division ring part but I am stuck. So I'm just asking to help me out here and I'm not asking a subquestion.

Comment: @RioDutta OK: the combination of the slightly different hypothesis and the request you are making is enough to convince me to reverse my vote.  I'll keep thinking about your question as posted.

Comment: @RioDutta now your root question really does have a complete answer at the linked question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint- any infinite group has infinitely many subgroups. If the ring operation is trivial, what are the ideals?